# How to remove hardcoded widths and offsets from vertical drop-down menu

Tags: css

After following a couple of tutorials I have managed to build up a CSS-only vertical drop-down menu. However, the widths and absolute offsets are hardcoded and I cannot get them to adjust automatically according to their contents. I wish to avoid hardcoding these because I wish to integrate it into a CMS where I don't know the actual lengths of the menu items.

I have created a JSFiddle here showing the menu working: http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/2/

The top level items are currently hardcoded to a width of 100px (I wish to make this adjust according to the longest item at that level.) When I tried to remove that, it just expanded the next sub-level all over the screen.

```
#navigation 
{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #707070;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 100px;  /* I wish to remove this */
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

The x offset of the sub-levels is also hard-coded. I wish them to just adjust according to their parent's width. Their width is also hardcoded to 200px.

```
li:hover .sub-level 
{
  background: #D0D0D0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px; /* I wish to remove this */
  top: 0px;
}

li:hover .sub-level .sub-level 
{
  left: 210px; /* I wish to remove this */
  top: 0px;
}

ul.sub-level li 
{
  border: none;
  float:left;
  width: 200px; /* I wish to remove this */
}
```

I wish to avoid Javascript if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` I believe gets you what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/14/

```
#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #707070;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#nav ul li {
    padding: 1px 5px;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}
#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #707070;
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the link actually this http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/4/? because the one included above displays the sub-sub-level all on one line instead of one underneath each other, but this one (which I presume you fixed too) displays them correctly.

Comment: The only remaining issue I have now is that the width of the items is not aligned and looks funny. When the items have different lengths, the sub-level is not popping up from the same horizontal offset. Is there a way to make the popup's x coordinate relative to the <ul> rather than the <li> (or make the <li>'s width as large as the largest one in the set)? You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/8/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Sorry, not sure if I understood your comment. The fiddle I pasted was Fiddle 4, just with the items longer. I have a clearer example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/9/ Item 2's sub-level opens underneath Item 1 instead of at the end of the largest width of the list. It becomes even uglier when opening Sub item 1.1 as it covers Sub item 1.2.

Comment: I took your advice and managed to do it with some ugly JQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/11/ Will proceed with this for now, maybe someone will have some pure CSS idea in the meantime.

Comment: LOL! No, look at my answer. I *know* I did it without JS and I didn't just learn how absolute/relative positioning relationships work. Muhammad, let's just try and post quality answers and comments and leave the voting to decide who's answer is worth looking at.

Comment: Wow this is nice working without JS now. Small thing however, there is this at the top now: `* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`, which will effect other elements in my page. Is there a way to remove it and have the same effect? Another question, if I wanted the top of the sub levels to be aligned with the first item, rather than their parent item (so Sub Item 2.1 would be vertically aligned to the top of Item 1), is there a way how to do it in CSS?

Comment: Never mind the `* { margin: 0; padding: 0;` question, I just did `#nav ul 
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;   
}` instead of it. Would still like to know if its possible to align them all to the top of the top-most `<ul>` vertically.

Comment: Managed to do the second one too, simply by moving `position: relative` to the `<ul>`. http://jsfiddle.net/nhfHw/15/ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here just what the answer above me did, but without bugs...

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/UBgZf/2/ **Updated**

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
.main{position:relative;}
ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
.main>li>ul{
    background-color:#BDBDBD;
}
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color:white;
    background-color:gray;
    float:left;
}
li{
    height:20px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px;
    clear:both;
}
li:hover>ul{
    background-color:black;
    display:block;
}
```

Tricks include:

- White Space No wrap
- float
- absolute positioning so it always refer to first element that has been positioned either absolute or relative.

Comment: i learned that absolute positioning can refer to parent that has not been positioned relative but can be absolute

Comment: Less Css..and better structure.
However, there are two ways to do it. One using inline-block and one using this. Float has better back browser support though.

Comment: Updated with some jquery to make it look less awkward. :D Some good animation.

Comment: Why not use CSS3 animations/transformations instead, so then the original request to avoid JS is honored, and then it gracefully degrades for older browsers. Or have you not learned that yet?

Comment: umm what.. css animation is basic stuff. And no it's not good enough for i want to do next. I want it to stay visible if mouse is out of main ul for a second, but if its on next li then disappear.

Comment: and i dont use css animation i remember reading that it slows down on mobile a lot. Not sure about it these days that was like some years ago. Also i want menu to be smart, i want it to appear only if mouse slows down on it or stops. Menu to disappear if mouse slows down or stops on other li.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Thanks for your help and insights too. I prefer CSS-only solutions wherever possible, but its always good to learn about fallback solutions when you're cornered. +1 for your answer too.

Comment: this is css only js part is for effects that is not in answer above. If you remove js part it behaves just like top answer.